# Inside virtual env, "sudo pip" links to the global python pip

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

Working inside a vagrant environment, inside a python virtual environment, when I try to install a python package using

```
(venv) vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ pip install <package_name>
```

I receive a permission error:

```
error: could not create '/home/vagrant/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/<package_name>': Permission denied
```

When I use sudo to install:

```
(venv) vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ sudo pip install <package_name>
```

the install is successful, but the package is not installed inside venv, but instead inside the global python directory.

I can successfully install the package inside venv by using `sudo` and specifying the path to pip:

```
(venv) vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ sudo /home/vagrant/venv/bin/pip install <package_name>
```

This is quite convoluted though. So how can I stop `sudo pip` linking to the global python pip?

Thank you

Comment: How did you set up the virtual environment?

Comment: You shouldn't try to stop sudo doing what it's supposed to; you should be fixing the original permission issue.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem with pip vs sudo pip and virtualenv pip vs local pip.
I was logged in as root user when I created my venv months ago. So when I wanted to install a new pip package got permission denied. So tried the same command with sudo, but then it installed the package on my local pip.

Lesson learned. I should not use sudo inside a venv.

Fixed it with:

```
chmod -R 0777 venv_folder_path_here
```

-R switch for recursive change in venv folder.

And then activate your venv and try pip install:

```
/home/username_here/venv/project_name_here/bin/activate
(venv_name) pip install package_name_here
```

Answer (score 5):

The root problem is that `sudo` does not by default inherit the user's environment as it executes the command. This is what you want - trust me on this.

In your case, your `pip` is either guided to the venv that it can't write to or - under sudo - to root's environment where you don't want it to be.

The solution you posted is actually valid: If you use sudo, be sure to tell it exactly what to do, how to do it and whom to do it to! All of the aforementioned can be controlled by the user's environment variables so caution is key.

You may also use `sudo -E`, which does inherit the calling user's environment and should therefore preserve your venv. Be sure to read `sudo`'s man-page or do some googling about all the possible trouble you could get in, though.

Answer (score 1):

Like Daniel said in comments, you should fix the permissions issue with your virtual environment directory. It could be that you already installed something in that directory with sudo. Or you created it with sudo. Which is not ideal. I recommend destroying the virtualenv and then creating it again with the vagrant user. If you are using `pyvenv`, make sure you pass `--copies` option.

As user27... said in their answer, the pip you run with sudo is probably not the same pip you run as vagrant user. You can always check that with `which pip`.

I'd recommend starting with `which python` inside your python virtual environment. Perhaps you have activated the wrong virtual environment, not related to your vagrant user at all.